# JOptionPane close frame on No button

Tags: java, netbeans, switch-statement, joptionpane, system.exit

I have this code snippet on a JOptionPane. I wanted to open another frame when the Yes button is clicked and close the frame when either No or Cancel is clicked.

Before I set the case 1 and case 2 to System.exit(0); the case 0 works perfectly fine because it successfully opens another frame. But when I put system.exit to both case 1 and 2 when the Yes button is clicked it still closes the frame.

```
int test = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "You lost! Play again?");

         switch(test) {
             case 0:  RPS rps = new RPS();
                        rps.setVisible(true);
                        this.dispose(); //Yes option
             case 1: System.exit(0); //No option
             case 2: System.exit(0); //Cancel option
           }
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: `break` statement missing

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put `break` statements in your code.

After the edit, your code could look like this:

```
int test = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "You lost! Play again?");
switch(test) {
case 0: RPS rps = new RPS();
        rps.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose(); // Yes option
        break;
case 1: System.exit(0); // No option
case 2: System.exit(0); // Cancel option
}
```

It is better that you use constants provided by the `JOptionPane`, as follows:

```
int test = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "You lost! Play again?");
switch(test) {
case YES_OPTION: RPS rps = new RPS();
                 rps.setVisible(true);
                 this.dispose(); // Yes option
                 break;
case NO_OPTION: System.exit(0); // No option
case CANCEL_OPTION: System.exit(0); // Cancel option
}
```